# Spring boot websocket send jsonstring

Tags: java, spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm new to spring boot, and I'm trying to send back jsonstring using websocket but I don't think it is returning correct jsonstring format.

RMModel.java

```
public class RMModel {
    private Integer inQueue;
    private Integer suspended;

    public RMModel getMessage() {
        this.inQueue = new Random().nextInt(11);
        this.suspended = new Random().nextInt(11);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + "\"inqueue\":" + this.inQueue + "," + "\"suspended\":" + this.suspended + '}';
    }
}
```

WebSocketScheduler.java

```
@Component
public class WebSocketScheduler {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void publishData() {
        String data = RMModel.getData().toString();
        this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/recon", data);
    }
}
```

So I want to return RMModel's jsonstring to the client. I have angular2 client

```
this._stompService.subscribe('/topic/recon').subscribe(res => console.log(JSON.parse(res.body)));
```

It is not converting to json object.
What is the correct way to return jsonstring in spring boot?

Comment: do you get any error or something? In any case, having that `toString` to build the json object is really fishy. If you pass your RMModel to the convertAndSend, under the hood, it will convert it to a json string as you would expect it to be (it uses `jackson` to accomplish that)

Comment: That's what I thought too.
But the client doesn't receive anything but string object... I have no idea why

Comment: try sending the RMModel directly and not send it like a string and see if it is still the problem. I only have a working angular 1.x that I tested on and it worked fine. Maybe angular 2 is a different kind of beast xD

Comment: I have tried that, there's no error on the server side, but the client side doesn't receive anything...

Answer (score 1):

problem solved.
The model shouldn't have a method that returns itself, jackson will throw an exception.

RMModel.java

```
public class RMModel {
    private Integer inQueue;
    private Integer suspended;

    public Integer getInQueue() {
        return inQueue;
    }

    public void setInQueue(Integer maximum) {
        this.inQueue = new Random().nextInt(maximum);
    }

    public Integer getSuspended() {
        return suspended;
    }

    public void setSuspended(Integer maximum) {
        this.suspended = new Random().nextInt(maximum);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + "\"inqueue\":" + this.inQueue + "," + "\"suspended\":" + this.suspended + '}';
    }
```

Comment: I guess that content-type will be text/plain instead of application/json. In my case if I try to manually set the content type of the message then the JSON is escaped (so it is actually a JSON string not a JSON object).